# Looking for an Excel Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a table full of numbers with with headings. I also have a separate list of numbers that are contained in the table. I would like to find the location of each number on the list, in the table. I would then like to use the cell location to provide the corresponding row heading. I demonstrated what I'm looking for below.

How do I go about doing this? I'm imagining some combination of index/match functions, or perhaps vlookup, but none of the formulas that I've tried have worked so far. I'm completely lost at this point, so any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Imagine something like this:

Table:

```
 - Category A   1   2  3  4  5
 - Category B   6   7  8  9  10
 - Category C   11  12 13 14 15
 - Category D   16  17 18 19 20
 - Category E   21  22 23 24 25
```

List:

- 22
- 5
- 10
- 4
- 18
- 6
- 14
- 2

Desired Outcome:

```
 - 22  Category E
 - 5   Category A
 - 10  Category B
 - 4   Category A
 - 18  Category D
 - 6   Category B
 - 14  Category C
 - 2   Category A
```

Comment: The desired outcome is what I'd like to get, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Your solution might work, but I think it's more complicated than I need. I don't want to create a new table (in actuality we're talking thousands of rows-not 5); I just want a formula. Thanks anyway though. If no one responds with a formula I'll try your solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:  Find the row that the matching value is in**

You can find the matching row by using a combination of a boolean function and SUMPRODUCT:

```
SUMPRODUCT((dataRange=22)*ROW(dataRange))
```

(note that this assumes that the items are all unique; it will not work if you have more than one match)

**Step 2: find the category for that row**

```
OFFSET(categoryACell, rows, 0)
```

so the resulting function would be:

```
OFFSET(categoryACell, SUMPRODUCT(--(dataRange=22)*ROW(dataRange)), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        A           |   B   |   C   |   D   |   E   |   F
    _________________________________________________________
1   ||  Category A  |   1   |   2   |   3   |   4   |   5
2   ||  Category B  |   6   |   7   |   8   |   9   |   10
3   ||  Category C  |   11  |   12  |   13  |   14  |   15
4   ||  Category D  |   16  |   17  |   18  |   19  |   20
5   ||  Category E  |   21  |   22  |   23  |   24  |   25
6   ||  
7   ||  
8   ||  
9   ||  
10  ||  22          |   =INDIRECT("A"&SUMPRODUCT((B1:F5=A10)*ROW(B1:F5)))               
11  ||  5           |   =INDIRECT("A"&SUMPRODUCT((B1:F5=A11)*ROW(B1:F5)))               
12  ||  10          |   =INDIRECT("A"&SUMPRODUCT((B1:F5=A12)*ROW(B1:F5)))               
13  ||  4           |   =INDIRECT("A"&SUMPRODUCT((B1:F5=A13)*ROW(B1:F5)))               
14  ||  18          |   =INDIRECT("A"&SUMPRODUCT((B1:F5=A14)*ROW(B1:F5)))               
15  ||  6           |   =INDIRECT("A"&SUMPRODUCT((B1:F5=A15)*ROW(B1:F5)))               
16  ||  14          |   =INDIRECT("A"&SUMPRODUCT((B1:F5=A16)*ROW(B1:F5)))               
17  ||  2           |   =INDIRECT("A"&SUMPRODUCT((B1:F5=A17)*ROW(B1:F5)))
```